# Open Edge in a new process and kill it again

Tags: c#, microsoft-edge

I'm currently making a program, that essentially needs to open a link in Edge, take a screenshot and then close the browser again.

**1st issue:**

I can open the browser just fine, but it just opens a new tab instead of a new window, if the browser's already open.
I do not want to interfere with an already existing open Edge browser, that our users may be using, but instead open a completely new instance, take a screenshot and then close it again.

I tried using the following, with no luck - it still just opens a new tab

```
Process proc = new Process();
proc.StartInfo.FileName = "microsoftedge.exe";
proc.StartInfo.Arguments = "http://172.31.44.1/#/cameras" + " --new-window";
proc.Start();
```

**2nd issue:**

When trying to kill the process using `proc.Kill()` I end up getting a ***system.invalidoperationexception cannot process request because the process has exited*** , but the browser's still open

Any help is appreciated!
Thank you in advance

Comment: The Process that initializes and shows a new Edge Window is not the same Process that owns that Window after it's presented. The stub Process has already exited at that point. -- You can use UIAutomation to be notified when  a new Window is opened, compare its class, title, whatever to determine whether it's the one you care about, then close it when you're done. -- See [WindowPattern.WindowOpenedEvent](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.automation.windowpattern.windowopenedevent) -- Another way, if possible, is to use WebView2 to render the page.

Comment: Tried to find a solution for killing the spawned MS Edge process but did not succeed. Edge seems to spawn several processes depending on installed browser extensions etc. Simply getting the Process by ID (proc.Id) and then calling .Kill() or starting a taskkill.exe /PID <ID> /f process also didn't work. The returned proc.Id does not seem to match the actual browser PID when looking in Task Manager.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this out:

using System.Diagnostics;

```
Process proc = new Process();
proc.StartInfo.FileName = @"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft\Edge\Application\msedge.exe";
proc.StartInfo.Arguments = " --new-window http://google.com";
proc.Start();
```

Comment: Cool! That seem to do the trick with opening a new instance of Edge :) Do you have any idea how I can then close it again? I still get the exception as mentioned in the question

Comment: I search a lot. It seems that Edge create some more processes for stability reasons. Also the starter process, exits right after creating the other processes.

Answer (score 0):

It seems as though Chrome (and therefor also Edge) has changed the behavior of this recently.

It used to be the case that you could use the parameter "--no-service-autorun" to avoid the browser closing the original process, and to avoid you ending up with an invalid (dead) process id.
This doesn't work anymore.

When "Startup boost" is disabled in Edge, the first window does have the correct process id, but anything after that is still invalid.

The only thing that I could find that works, is to use "--user-data-dir" parameter to give each process it's own profile and process.
For example, use "msedge.exe --user-data-dir=C:\test123" (make sure each process has a unique directory).