# How to close an exited process through winforms c#? Or how to not let a process exit early in c#?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I am coding a winforms program where screenshots of the active screen have to be taken periodically at specific times.

My aim is to open a **browser window (with a specified url)** before the screenshot is taken, and then close it once the screenshot happens. This will be then sent by email to multiple users.

My problem is that once the Kill() function is reached the process has already exited although the browser window is still open and the following error occurs: **System.InvalidOperationException: 'Cannot process request because the process has exited.'**

I tried multiple approaches to overcome this problem e.g. using **WaitForExit()**, wrapping the Kill() and CloseMainWindow() in a **try and catch** and using the **using** keyword for when initialising the process.

Here is a snippet of the code, please help as I can't found many other options :)

```
//check times for the day
                    if (timeSlots.Items[index_t].ToString() == time)
                    {
                        //opening link
                        var proc = Process.Start("MicrosoftEdge.exe", "https://www.google.com/");
                        Thread.Sleep(10000); //waiting for webpage to load

                        //Take Screenshot
                        TakeScreenshot();

                        //closing the browser window
                        proc.Kill();
                        proc.CloseMainWindow();

                        //send email to all recipients if day and time matches
                        SendEmail();

                        index_t += 1; //append index

                        Thread.Sleep(50000); //wait till another minute to exit condition (if not then multiple emails will be sent during the matched time until the current time changes)

                        
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        index_t += 1; //append index to check the next time slot
                    }
```

Answer (score 0):

See [this comment by Jimi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71660608/open-edge-in-a-new-process-and-kill-it-again#comment126648253_71660608) who explained the issue and provided a potential solution to your problem using UI Automation and WindowOpenedEvent.

Comment: I checked the link provided, but no Automation module is being detected from Visual Studio, I am using .Net Framework 4.7.2

Comment: You might need to add a reference manually to your project (right click on the project => add => reference)

Comment: I just cheked, UI Automation is available for WPF and not Winforms

Comment: From what I'm reading, while it is fully supported on WPF, it is a general API made to work with win32 apps, so the fact that you're using WinForms shouldn't be a problem. I believe ```UIAutomationClient.dll``` is what you're looking for to start with. You might also find those chapters useful (starting with the Overview chapter): [MS on UI Automation](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/ui-automation/implement-ui-automation-providers-in-a-client-application) and perhaps getting to know UI automation more deeply will prove useful to you in the future given your current task.

Comment: Yes I added the **UIAutomationClient.dll** via the method you told me but still visual studio can't seem to pick it up, nonetheless thanks for the help I will look into it :)